# Practicality of a 5d array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, language-agnostic

In my class I have to write a program to create and add data to a 5d array in Java. Fairly easy.

However, what I would like to ask is: **Is a 5d array used in real-life programming?**

Would it not be a bad design to use such a complex structure ? Should not the programmer focus on making it into a simpler data structure ?

Comment: It certainly is complex, but if the data/domain is five dimensional, what else are you supposed to do?

Comment: @delnan when can such a thing happen ?

Comment: Doubtful.  In ~20 years of coding business systems, I rarely do a 2D array.  Unless you consider a Map a type of 2D array.

Comment: Just because a structure exists and is complex does not mean it is bad design. Bad design is in how things are applied. I can think on the top of my mind about two scenarios where you could have structures with five dimensions or more: particle physics and weather prediction.

Comment: Speaking in general, is not possible to say if a data structure is "simple" or "complex" without referring to what you are actually abstracting. When dealing with, say, 5-variable probability, a 5D array makes sense and it is the most natural choice. On the other hand, when dealing with a hypothetical database, a `struct` is much more appropriate than a multidimensional array could be.

Answer (score 2):

Why not?

A five-dimensional array is a mapping from five indexes to one value. If you have this exact requirement, a five-dimensional array is probably the most efficient as well as the most readable way to implement this mapping.

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in fighting a naturally occurring data structure prematurely: if your data has five dimensions to it when you think about it in your mind, then modeling it with a 5D array in your code is your best strategy.

The only reason to go for a different data structure is if your 5D array happens to be very sparse: by their nature, arrays pre-allocate space eagerly, resulting in sub-par use of memory on very sparse structures. Moreover, that seemingly sub-par use of space may be more than paid for by better performance: arrays represent an extreme point in space-for-speed tradeof due to their simplicity, so "wasting" a few megabytes of space in return for some trillions of CPU cycles may not be a bad deal.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** it is used. **But** for simple things as websites not as much. 
If you would have to make complex physics(general relativity, computational chemistry, quantum physics) or mathematical applications. There might be enough reasons to do so.
For example: [Tensor applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Applications)

In Matlab people use 4d matrices all the time.

There are of course **bad examples** of using high dimensional arrays just for indexing purpose.

An example of **bad** practice:

```
$clothes["type"]["color"]["price"]["size"] = ...
```

@Renan said it in the comments, it's all about how you apply high dimensional arrays.

Comment: Fair enough. I appreciate the example. However, You could make 4 arrays, each having information regarding something. Then use the same index values in each array to get the information

Comment: I did not downvote you. In fact, I did to the contrary

Comment: @Little child : was talking about someone else (he removed his comment).You are right you can easily combat high dimensional arrays. But not all information is as simple as you think. Think about Quantum physics complex math.  Not only too complex to just save, you might not want to save data because you need computational power to do maths, not to do queries to get your values all the time.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, usually anything above 3D is frowned upon. It usually makes more sense to start breaking things out into classes/structs instead of indexing by a numeric index. I've never seen a data set with more than 4 numerically-indexable dimensions. There's a fluid dynamics application I was looking at the other day that used a `float[][][][]` for the computation.

Really, it comes down to whether your data is *actually* 5D, or if you're just mapping what could be better represented as nested classes/structs onto arrays.

Comment: You raise an interesting point. I'm not sure whether sticking some class in between the dimensions makes the data any less five dimensional. Of course, it's not literally a 5D array any more, but it's nested five levels deep and a `float[][][][][]` is also just an array nested in an array nested in an array ... and so on.

Comment: Even I remember reading that you should go for a maximum of 3 dimensions which is `an array of 2d arrays`

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, if there is the option of a simpler structure then it probably should be investigated. There are, however, times when performance outweighs simplicity (3D graphics? Database engines? Countless other examples) and keeping it simple is not an option.

For the most part data you'd encounter building shopping web sites can be made 2D - it fits inside a database table after all, so the example posted here by someone else isn't entirely relevant (Clothes[color][type]...) - this is just a 2D database table with such columns.

In the rare occasions where higher dimension data is needed (I can't even think one up!) I'm pretty sure you'll recognize it because of the inherent difficulties of lower dimensions' use would entail, despite being possible.

Comment: It's not that rare. Don't forget programming isn't only for web development. He was talking about programming in general. Were talking about computational applications regarding physics, maths, chemistry, quantum physics etc. etc.

Comment: @TimDinh that' true and that's why I put "countless other examples" in my answer; I just couldn't come up with a real example